# How come npm install doesn't work on git bash

Tags: node.js, git, shell, npm, git-bash

I have git bash open and I type in `npm install` and then it returns:

```
bash: npm command not found
```

I don't understand, because I have `node.js` command prompt and when I type in `npm -v` then it returns `3.7.3`. How come it doesn't work in git?

Answer (score 50):

In our case, the solution was simply to close the Git bash window and re-open it.

Answer (score 35):

In git bash type ...

```
which npm
```

This will tell you where npm is installed.

Now, I'm assuming this will give you nothing since it seems npm is not on your system PATH variable. The PATH variable defines where Windows looks for commands.

Go into your control panel and click system advanced settings and add the directory containing npm to your path.

If you dont know where it is then open a normal windows console and type ...

```
where npm
```

This will show you where it is so you can add it to your path.

Then close your git bash terminal and reopen it and npm should work.

PS if you want to check the PATH variable inside git bash, make sure the correct npm folder is on the PATH then just type ...

```
echo $PATH
```

PPS Another tip - you can tweak the PATH for git bash only via your .bashrc OR .bash_profile files.

Comment: This is super helpful in case you, say, happened to install two versions of node in two separate directories, and can't figure out why bash isn't picking up the new one.

Comment: You should take care of the sequence of entries in the PATH also. If you have chocolately in your PATH move it down below nodejs to fix the issue in git bash.

Answer (score 18):

If you are on Windows, try this:
In CMD, go to folder

```
C:\Program Files or (x86)\nodejs\
```

Then try the following

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>set path=%PATH%;%CD%
C:\Program Files\nodejs>setx path "%PATH%"
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 12):

If you installed git bash first and then node.js, uninstall gitbash and keep node.js.
And then re-install git bash again.

```
npm --version
node --version
```

check version using this command

Comment: The first thing to try if you did this is to restart PC. Worked for me. And did not need to reinstall git bash

Answer (score 4):

The default terminal emulator installed by git is named [Mintty](https://mintty.github.io/). To run `npm` with Mintty, you need to add the path to an environment variable.

Add the following line to your `~\.bash_profile` file. If it does not exist, create it.

```
PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
```

When Mintty starts up it will read `.bash_profile`. You should now be able to run `npm` from Mintty.

These other questions might be helpful also.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path
https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables

Answer (score 2):

you need to add nodejs to your path, along with npm

> where node
>
> where npm

Comment: Just complementing... If you are using Git Bash inside VSCode you will need to restart VSCode to load the new `$PATH`.

Comment: @fernandosavio thanks for that!  Despite VSCode having Git Bash set as the default shell, I had to restart to load the updated $PATH.

Comment: Just to complete further more, PhpStorm needs a restart as well for it to work 

Answer (score 2):

Are you on Windows?

If so, can you go to the Git Bash console and run:

```
echo $PATH
```

and then check if the node path(e.g. c/Program Files/node ) is there?

If the node path is not there you'll need to add it to the system path variable.

If it's there, can you try to run npm between double quotes?

```
"npm"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on Windows trying git-bash, and node was installed by Visual Studio: The cause may be a missing `npm` bash script.

There is an `npm.cmd` bath file in the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\npm.cmd
```

But `git bash` wont run `.cmd` files. So you need to create a bash script for npm.

Create the following file named `npm` in your node folder: (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\`)

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Comment: I'm getting `/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/NodeJs/npm: line 1: #!/bin/sh: No such file or directory
6.1.0`

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed node / npm in a drive other than the os drive you will need to node and npm to the path environment variable (windows) right click on this pc go to advanced system settings -> environment variables -> double click on path and add

**Drive**:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin

**Drive**:\nodejs

click ok and close the opened cli and open it again to check in cli run :

```
echo "$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I successed to solve it by changing the **git** enviornment system variable from ***C:\Program Files\Git\cmd*** to ***C:\Program Files\Git***

Hope that will help someone

Answer (score 0):

I had to add node path to system variable AND reboot. For some reason closing and reopening git bash was not enough

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but this could help someone who installed `Node / npm` via `Visual Studio Installer`. I tried every solution I could find online but none works until I did the following:

- Uninstall `Node` using `Visual Studio Installer`.
- Install it using installer downloaded from the [Node.js site](https://nodejs.org/en/). Use default options.

Answer (score 0):

This option is work for me.

above mention ----

Uninstall Node using Visual Studio Installer.

Install it using installer downloaded from the Node.js site. Use default options.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old thread, but if anyone needs this :

As suggested by @fernandosavio, I restarted my IDE(IntelliJ in my case) in order for it to load the new `$PATH`, and it worked like a charm.

**Note:** Just closing and opening the in-house terminal of the IDE won't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have also faced this problem, so I found a solution.

• just go to programs and features of your control panel and search for Node...

• then just repair node. it worked fine for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You need to define this #!/bin/bash start of you bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install
```