# Setting args for Git bash in Shell Launcher VS Code extension

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have installed Shell Launcher Extension in VS Code and integrated Git bash terminal as follows:

```
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "args": ["--login","-i"],
        "label": "Git bash"
    }
```

[image]

But when I use "node" or "npm" in my git bash terminal it give this error:

**bash: node: command not found**

[image]

While it is working fine in the external Git Bash Terminal.

[image]

I applied this solution but no success

[see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915832/how-come-npm-install-doesnt-work-on-git-bash)

**P.S** Please ignore my little knowledge about VS code and do not block my question. Something is missing, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Those options you pass:`"--login","-i"` are contradicting to each other. Can you try removing both of them and see if it works? Also print `echo $PATH` for both when you run it from bash inside VS and from git-bash terminal, this is where it searches for commands.

Comment: echo $PATH for both is different. external terminal shows npm while inside VS code does not show
I have tried also with no args but still same issue.
@battlmonstr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {"PATH" : "/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/"}
```

With this:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {"PATH" : "/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files/nodejs"}
```

I have only added this to your path at the end **/c/Program Files/nodejs/**

See if it works.

Comment: Wonderful! 
You saved my day :)