# Git bash not displaying after entering "node"

Tags: node.js, bash, git, git-bash

I entered "node" into git bash terminal and press enter afterwards it display $, and whatever i type next doesn't appear, is there a working around for this bug/problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZegB.png)

[But here what ever i enter in the next line, it doesn't display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZegB.png)

[It worked on win cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WCu0.png)

Comment: @TGrif is it better for me to just stick to win cmd/node cmd? it because a book that im reading uses git bash.

Comment: Maybe node is [not in your PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320908/5156280) and _git-bash_ can't find it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `node -i` for interactive. (Only for windows git-bash)

Comment: Still appears blank afterwards and i cant type anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Just press `Ctrl+D` and you will go back to **Bash** and everything would be normal again.