# Unable to run node from git bash

Tags: node.js, bash, git

I am no longer able to run node from the git bash terminal. It works from Git CMD and the standard windows CLI. If I try to run a file (e.g. `node index.js`) or even just start node via `node`, I go back to the input prompt except now I can't see any of my character inputs.

This is not a result of PATH not being set, as `where node` gives me `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` and `which node` gives me `/c/Program Files/nodejs/node` and `echo $PATH` does have `/c/Program Files/nodejs` included.

If I type another command (such as `ls`), it actually will work even though I will continue to not be able to see my input.

I *think* this problem arose after the latest Windows 10 OS update was pushed to my system (10.0.17763). I've tried reinstalling Git for Windows and Node, and neither have resolved the issue. I can't find any other settings that might be affecting this.

Using Git CMD or Windows CLI is a workaround, but neither of those have a "Git Bash Here" option, which is the #1 thing I want this for. It is also nice that I get the visual indication of branch in Git Bash where I do not get that with Git CMD or the Windows CLI.

I don't need or want to use Git GUI, and besides that won't allow me to run local node files which I need to do for testing.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get Git Bash working with node again?

UPDATE: By running `stty -a` after node fails, I see that `echo` has flipped to `-echo`, which is why I can't see the input anymore. But that doesn't explain why node isn't loading and echo is getting turned off. Hoping that gives someone some additional context to figure out what's going on here. `brkint`, `icrnl`, `ixon`, `opost`, `isig`, and `icanon` are also getting flipped to the - versions after attempting to run node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come npm install doesn't work on git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915832/how-come-npm-install-doesnt-work-on-git-bash)

Comment: I don't think this is the same. I checked echo $PATH and `/c/Program Files/nodejs` is there. `where node` gives me back the path `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` so I think that should be fine. The issue is that when I DO run node from git bash, it doesn't work (either stand alone or trying to run a file).

Comment: I would check the environment variables to check if it is in the path. If you say it is there then I would try the turn it off, turn it back on method. Uninstall Nodejs, Uninstall Git, then Install Git first and Nodejs after. When installing GIt pick "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt"

Comment: V, are you suggesting this as a workaround to using Git Bash to run node? Git runs fine from Git Bash and I don't need it from Windows Command prompt, unless you are suggesting I don't use bash at all. The issue is node, not Git. I've already tried reinstalling both Git and Nodejs in that order.

Comment: I also had problems with Git Bash, quite different, but I solved them by installing the very last version. Just for information, perhaps you installed Node in a repertory with Git Bash and you installed an another Node in another repertory with Windows CLI. Consider to check it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried upgrading to the latest version of Git earlier this week to no avail. Also, path to node is the same from bash and Windows CLI.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible workarounds (based on what your problem is) that I have tried-

Enter `node` first of all:
1) Try typing in `reset` and hit enter. You may not be able to see the input logging in, in the bash terminal window, but it works after that.

2) Or try typing any random alphabet and hit enter(again you won't see it on the screen),it will throw a 'command not found' error but you will have node working after this.

I am afraid these aren't exactly proper fixes, but they get the job done.
More information can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/171449/shell-does-not-show-typed-in-commands-reset-works-but-what-happened/172747#172747