# Node and npm are installed but Git bash doesn't recognize 'node' inside 'npm run dev' (other shells work fine)

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, git, npm

I have npm and node installed (tried NVM for Windows and direct installations).

When running 'npm -v' or 'node -v' in **Git Bash** everythings works fine. But when I try to run 'npm run dev' (or any other command) the output says that 'node command is not recognized'.

In other shells (CMD/Powershell) everything works fine.

I've checked Path variable in Windows, Path variable in Git Bash, everything seems to be correct.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEc2G.png)
[Path variable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTT49.png)

[Path variables cmd/procmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Imd9.png)

Any help appreciated.

p.s. While I was trying to find an answer I saw the same [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1423919/in-git-bash-only-node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) from @jameseg , maybe if he sees this one he could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102323/unable-to-run-node-from-git-bash

Comment: @Sergio thank you, looks like it is. But that question wasn't answered and was asked a year ago. Maybe I have more luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How come npm install doesn't work on git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915832/how-come-npm-install-doesnt-work-on-git-bash)

Comment: @jpnadas Nope, I've tried all of the suggested options

Comment: You are showing us only your bash path variable but not the one from windows. Please start cmd from bash (so that it has a similar environment as npm would have) and do `echo %path%` there and show it too.

Comment: Also, did you try rebooting your computer? (or actually logging out and back in should be enough)

Comment: @CherryDT For some reason stackoverflow doesn't allow me to send one more screenshot, so

1) I am sure that in Windows PATH node and npm also exist
2) Tried almost everything except, maybe, Windows reinstallation :D

Comment: What is the result of the test I asked you to do (running cmd from git bash and then `echo %PATH%`)? You can paste it as text into the question instead of an image. Also, when you use Process Monitor (Google it) and filter for operation starting with "process" and then look at the details for the "process start" operation of the cmd process created by npm, what do you see the environment variables?

Comment: @CherryDT added screenshot of %path% from cmd and procmon

Comment: Answered! It's a stray doublequote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PATH` environment variable is quite a mess. It has duplicate entries, also has an entry `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` which is not valid because it should be a *folder*, not a *file*, and it has `.` in the middle which doesn't make much sense either.

But the main problem is that it has a **stray doublequote**, after `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin`:

[image: stray doublequote]

With this, effectively **all the paths after it are ignored**, because they are treated as part of one big quoted string (which is implicitly terminated by the end of the variable data).

---

To illustrate what I mean, consider this example:

This correct `PATH` variable...

```
C:\a;C:\b;"C:\c 123";C:\d;C:\e
```

...is interpreted as:

```
C:\a
C:\b
C:\c 123
C:\d
C:\e
```

But, this *bad* `PATH` variable where I deleted one of the quotes...

```
C:\a;C:\b;C:\c 123";C:\d;C:\e
```

...is interpreted like this:

```
C:\a
C:\b
C:\c 123";C:\d;C:\e
```

This may at first make only half sense, but it's because of the quirky way Windows parses this variable: When encountering a doublequote, it's removed from the result but toggles a flag that says whether we are now inside a quoted string. And when the flag is set, semicolons are ignored. So even if the stray quote is at the end of a path (or in the middle of it), it will have the effect of essentially quoting the rest of the variable data until the next doublequote or the end of the data.

Confusingly, you may still have `where node` report that it found node, because **the `where.exe` tool does its own parsing, in a slightly different way** (ignoring quotes), so you cannot rely on its output! (For example, try `set PATH=c:\win""dows`. `where explorer` will say it can't be found, yet `explorer` will work to open Explorer. You get the opposite with something like `set PATH=x"y;c:\windows` - `where explorer` will list `c:\windows\explorer.exe`, yet `explorer` will not work.) The reason why it works in Git Bash is probably the same: when the environment variables are translated to UNIX paths, they are parsed slightly differently than Windows would do it itself, inadvertently correcting the problematic entry in the process.

So, the solution is to remove this doublequote from your path variable.

Comment: Yes, it worked!

Thank you for your patienсe and attention, I would never solve this by myself.